# What are the chances of a creeper dropping a music disc?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When a creeper is killed by a skeleton arrow, what are the chances of it dropping a music disc?  I've gotten quite a few killed by skeletons and I still haven't seen one.  I'm wondering how long I should expect this to take.

(Unmodded Windows 10 Edition, if it matters.)

Comment: On Java edition it's 100% at least. You used the tag for the Java edition.

Comment: This is actually a good question. I can't find it on the English wiki, the German wiki and a special pocket edition wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional experimentation, I believe music discs do not exist in Windows 10 edition.  Not only have none dropped after numerous attempts, but I'm also unable to craft a jukebox, which seems to indicate they've been intentionally left out.

Comment: How ironic, jukeboxes were introduced 9 days after this post